# How to determine if View Controller is loaded due to Navigation Controller Generated Back button being clicked

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller having a child view controller. The child view controller does a specific task when it's loaded when the app launches for the first time. This specific task should not be repeated. When a button is clicked in child view controller, it navigates to a different scene. Navigation Controller creates a back button automatically. When back button is clicked, previous scene gets loaded, but I don't want the specific task I mentioned before to be repeated. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the back button in a navigation controller's navigation bar should pop the current view controller and expose the previous view controller without loading it again. The old view controller's viewWillAppear method will be called, but viewDidLoad will not.

The embed segue that loads the child view controller should not fire either (Assuming you're using container views and embed segues. Ignore this bit if you're not.)

Comment: In viewDidAppear, I pop a pop up in first time load. It's important that I pop it in viewDidAppear because I want the user to see the animation. How can I pop the pop up once, and not when back is clicked.

Comment: Add an instance variable `firstTimeRendered`. If it's FALSE in viewDidAppear, set it to true and do your animation.